# Heroku: Error al mostrar imagen con Node.js

Tags: nodejs, firebase, express

Tengo un sistema de upload de imágenes con firebase storage, las cuales muestro en una galería y cada imagen tiene un botón que redirige a la imagen original pero quiero enmascarar la imagen con una url virtual echa con Node.js.
Pero al intentar acceder a la dirección la que enmascara la imagen, Heroku me manda a la pagina de error predeterminada de Heroku https://www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html

Este es mi código:

```
    const app = express()
app.get('/img/:img', (req, res) => {
        const img = req.params.img
        const _get = fetch(`https://bucket.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/assets/${img}`)
        _get.then((buff) => {
            const size = buff.headers.get('Content-Length')
            const format = buff.headers.get('Content-Type')
            const _buffer = buff.arrayBuffer()
            _buffer.then((buffer) => {
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Length': size,
                    'Content-Type': format
                })
                const data = Buffer.from(buffer).toString('utf-8')
                res.render('render', {
                    results: data
                })
            }).catch((err) => {
                res.writeHead(404)
                res.render('render', {
                    results: err.message
                })
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Dos cosas que veo a simple vista: Usas `await` pero no estás dentro de una función tipo `async`, deberías usar: `app.get('/img/:img', async (req, res) => { ... })`. Luego, cuando se trabaja con Promesas usando `await` (`fetch` devuelve una Promesa), debes envolver la misma en un bloque `try/catch`. Empieza corrigiendo eso y comenta los resultados. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras adjunte mi nuevo código pero sigue sin mostrar la imagen.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ok, pero lo quiero generar es una url virtual con express que enmascare una imagen, la cual muestre la imagen directamente así http://myapp.herokuapp.com/img/picture.jpg o otra diferente http://myapp.herokuapp.com/pokemon.png, osea quiero generar urls dinámicas pero de imagenes

Comment: Ok, ya te entiendo, quieres que cuando un usuario acceda a una ruta de tu app que sea una imagen, tu app captura la imagen desde algún repositorio externo y la envía al cliente, ¿cierto?.

Comment: Igual, cuando haces: `_get.then((buff)`, no estás capturando un posible error al hacer `fetch`, el mismo debes capturarlo con `_get.catch((error) => { ... });`, de lo contrario el error se propagará deteniendo la ejecución de tu aplicación y `heroku` enviará la página que mencionas. Captura eso y verifica que funcione la captura, puedes enviar un estado HTTP 500 para indicar un error de servidor y un mensaje personalizado al cliente indicando que hubo un problema al obtener la imagen.

Comment: @MauricioContreras exacto eso es lo que quiero. Y es verdad me olvide de ese catch, solo hice el catch del `_buffer.arrayBuffer()` xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto mi problema, el problema era que no estaba instalando la dependencia de fetch para Node.js, la cual es `node-fetch`